# Normalize monthly payments

Tags: sql, database, normalization, database-normalization

First, sorry for my bad English. I'm trying to normalize a table in a pension system where subscribers are paid monthly. I need to know who has been paid and who has not and how much they've been paid.  I believe I'm using SQL Server.  Here's an example:

```
id_subscriber  id_receipt     year   month     pay_value   payment type_pay
 12               1           2016   January    100          80       1   
 13               1           2016   January    100          100      1 
 14               1           2016   January    100          100      1
 12               2           2016   February   100          100      2
 13               2           2016   February   100          80       1
```

But I'm not happy repeating the year and the month for every single subscriber.  It doesn't seem right.  Is there a better way to store this data?

**EDIT:** 
The case is as follows: this company has many subscribers who must pay monthly and payment can be in various ways. They produce a single receipt for many customers, and each customer that receipt may be paying one or more installments.

These are my other tables:

```
                           tbl_subscriber
id_suscriber(PK) first_name  last_name  address  tel_1  tel_2
    12             Juan         Perez      xxx     xxx    xxx
    13             Pedro        Lainez     xxx     xxx    xxx
    14             Maria        Lopez      xxx     xxx    xxx 

                           tbl_receipt
id_receipt(PK)      value        elaboration_date  deposit_date 
    1             1,000.00         2015-09-16       2015-09-20
    2             890.00           2015-12-01       2015-12-18 

                          tbl_type_paym
 id               type             description
 1                bank               xxxx
 2              ventanilla            xxx
```

Comment: Be more specific... What have you tried and what are you looking for?

Comment: Edit your question and include sample data, desired results, and the database you are actually using.

Comment: Your question is not clear Frank.

Comment: Use an small int to store the month.

Comment: You can't normalize without doing 3 things: 1. Define the level of normalization you want. 2. define your keys, define your determinants.

Comment: The first two columns are FK to separate tables, And those I have no problem. I Will change month to small int. I'm sorry for not understand me, but the lenguaje is my problem, I try it..

Comment: There might be a functional dependency involving "id_receipt", "year", and "month". It's not clear whether it might involve other attributes, too. You can't normalize this relation until you *know* the functional dependencies. None of us can tell you what the FDs are; you have to tell *us*.

Comment: Normalization involves knowing all functional dependencies. What are yours? Foreign keys are irrelevant. Please find out what normalization is from university/college texts or slides. (There are many online.) Because from this question, you don't know anything about it. Eg there is nothing wrong with (the situation you are apparently but poorly describing via) "repeating the year and the month for every single subscriber".

Answer (score -2):

This basically seems fine.  You *could* split dates out into a separate table and reference that, but that strikes me as a kind of silly way to do it.  I would recommend storing the month as an integer instead of a varchar column though.  Besides not storing the same string over and over you can more reasonably do comparisons.

You could also use date values, although that might not be worth the trouble when you don't want greater granularity than the month.

Comment: What's the natural key?

Comment: @nicomp Ha, ha, well, I guess you'd have an artificial key in this scenario.  Like I said, I don't see any benefit to splitting out.  But there isn't anything stopping you.

Comment: Well it's not even 1NF then.

Comment: @nicomp Unless I'm missing something it satisfies first normal form as long as you don't allow multiple rows having the same month and year.

Comment: It's correct i don't need be more specific in the date. I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: 1NF requires each row to be unique from all the other rows, that means a natural key.

Comment: And if I create another table that contains year and month as the primary key and I refer to it, would that be correct?

Comment: @nicomp You can simply put a unique index on the combination of year and month and you have satisfied that constraint.

Comment: @Frank I really don't recommend doing that.

Comment: @Casey I will follow your advice, you give me an example of how it is done the unique index in this case?

Comment: @Frank My advice is to keep your current structure.  It'll cause you headaches to split them out without any real gain.

Comment: @Casey Thank you for the help, I will follow your advice. Best regard.